# Regular expression for 6 or 8 digits

Tags: c#, regex

Could anyone please help with C# regular expression for requirement below, please?

1. should start with 1 and should be 6 digit long.
2. should start with 7 and should be 6 digit long.
3. should be 8 digit long.

Update:
Apologies not clarifying the requirement. They are individual cases ie. all I need is a regular expression to these specific cases (i.e. 3 in total).

Comment: It can't match all those requirements :)

Comment: This is quite specific requirements. Can you give some samples on what you're trying to match?

Comment: I'd also take a look at a non-regex approach, especially if it is a portion of code needing performance tuning.  The hand-written fine-tuned approach will out perform the equivalent regular expression 99 out of 100 times.  And the non-regex code may even be easier to understand from a maintainability standpoint.

Comment: hi @Jason McCreary, I've updated my requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is:

```
^((1|7)\d{5}|\d{8})$
```

or following NullUserException ఠ_ఠ advice:

```
^([17]\d{5}|\d{8})$
```

Comment: +1. Except we don't know yet if (8 digits long) condition includes those starting with 1 and 7.

Answer (score 5):

Not a regular expression, and now verifies a proper integer and save it into `output`:

```
string digits = ...
bool valid;
char firstChar;
int output;

switch(digits.Length) 
{
    case 6:
        firstChar = digits[0];
        valid = firstChar == '1' || firstChar == '7';
        break;
    case 8:
        valid = true;
        break;
    default:
        valid = false;
        break;
}

if (valid && int.TryParse(digits, out output))  
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You sure that's not a regular expression?

Comment: Why not `bool valid = Regex.IsMatch(digits, @"^([17]\d{5}|\d{8})$")` instead of 13 lines of code (that is wrong BTW)?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ, now it does and you get the actual integer when you are done

Comment: Currently it is fine, but it need to be rewritten in case if in some reason limit of 8 digits will be increased to 10

Comment: @zerkms, it could use long if needed